# Powershell and Adobe OCR

Tags: windows, powershell

we have many pdf files they are all unlocked they have text, pictures etc. everytime we have to open the file on adobe and do it manually i was thinking maybe there is a better way to do with PowerShell if not yeah we have to do over 1000 files and more are coming but thank you for your answer
Peggy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into it a bit more, I discovered a command-line tool that you can use in tangent with PowerShell. It's called **tesseract**. For Windows and Linux, download the [prebuilt binaries](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Home.html#binaries). For MacOS, you need to get use [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/tesseract/) or [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/tesseract).

You'll want to do something like this:

```
# Using Get-ChildItem's -Include parameter to filter file types
# requires the target path to end in an asterisk. Using just an
# asterisk as the path makes it target the current directory.
foreach ($pdf in (Get-ChildItem * -Include *.pdf))
{
  # An array isn't needed, it's just good for arranging arguments
  tesseract @(
    #INPUT:
    $pdf
    #OUTPUT:
    "$($pdf.Directory)\{OCR} $($pdf.Name)"
    #LANGUAGE:
    '-l','eng'
  )
  # The directory is included in the output path so that you can
  # change Get-ChildItem's target without adjusting the argument
}
```

Or, without the fluff:

```
foreach ($pdf in (Get-ChildItem * -Include *.pdf))
{
  tesseract $pdf "$($pdf.Directory)\{OCR} $($pdf.Name)" -l eng
}
```

Granted, I haven't actually tested tesseract out, but I did read other Q&A pages to derive the appropriate command. Let me know if there's any issues.

Comment: thank you Vopel i will check it and let you know 

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. There is a way to OCR images using PowerShell, such as using [this function](https://github.com/HumanEquivalentUnit/PowerShell-Misc/blob/master/Get-Win10OcrTextFromImage.ps1), and you can convert pdfs to images using [this function](https://perplexity.nl/toolbox/convert-pdf-to-images-using-powershell-and-imagemagick/) (it does require imagemagick, which is available [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php), there are portable options if yuo don't want to install anything). This would effectively allow you to search PDF files that haven't been OCR'd.

However, in terms of directly editing the PDF files with PowerShell to make them into OCR'd PDFs, while PowerShell functionality might help you automate the process, you would first need to find a program that can do that sort of thing from the command line. The PDFs would also have to all be unlocked so that editing them would even be possible (though there are ways to circumvent PDF locks to unlock them).

Unfortunately, I don't really know of any programs that can do that. Maybe it's possible with some advanced [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/) parameters, but I haven't looked into it. It is certainly not going to be easy!

Comment: Hi Vogel, we have many pdf files they are all unlocked they have text, pictures etc. everytime we have to open the file on adobe and do it manually i was thinking maybe there is a better way to do with PowerShell if not yeah we have to do over 1000 files and more are coming but thank you for your answer